# npm issue while trying to npm install dependencies

Tags: apt, package-management, nodejs, npm

```
pkcs11js@1.0.16 install /home/ubuntu/blockchainpoc/hlpoc/node_modules/pkcs11js
> node-gyp rebuild

gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/ubuntu/blockchainpoc/hlpoc/node_modules/pkcs11js/build'
gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1060-aws
gyp ERR! command "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd /home/ubuntu/blockchainpoc/hlpoc/node_modules/pkcs11js
gyp ERR! node -v v8.11.2
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! pkcs11js@1.0.16 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the pkcs11js@1.0.16 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/ubuntu/.npm/_logs/2018-06-12T07_38_09_022Z-debug.log
```

1. I am using node version 
   8.11.2
2. I am using npm version 
   5.6.0
3. I used sudo when typing npm install
4. I uninstalled completely and installed again by using the following
   commands

   ```
   sudo apt-get remove nodejs
   sudo apt-get remove npm
   ```
5. I cleared the cache and restarted the instance

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by installing gyp with:

```
pip install git+https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/gyp --user
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to install gyp with:

```
apt-get install node-gyp
```